# How to use ArcView GIS extension in QGIS or how to convert one to do so?

Tags: qgis-plugins, arcview-3

I really would like to know whether is a way to can work with ArcView GIS extensions at QGIS? or at least a way to be converted to plugins at QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

The ArcView GIS (versions 2.x,3.x) architecture, which pre-dates the ArcView license level of ArcGIS (9.x,10.x), is very different to that of QGIS.

Consequently, there is no way to use an ArcView GIS extension with QGIS, nor any way to convert one to a QGIS plug-in.

My advice would be to look for a QGIS plug-in "equivalent" to any ArcView GIS extension that you are interested in.